# checking if callout view is pressed (mapBox iOS SDK)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, mapbox

i'm wondering what is the best way to check - is callout view pressed using mapBox iOS SDK?

The only method that i find is this one

`- (void)tapOnCalloutAccessoryControl:(UIControl *)control forAnnotation:(RMAnnotation *)annotation onMap:(RMMapView *)map`

but this method checking is accessory pressed in callout view.

Any ideas how to achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a delegate method called `tapOnLabelForAnnotation:onMap` in `RMMapViewDelegate`, you can use this method to get informed about the user tapping the annotation label.

Answer (score 0):

Delegate methods for detecting a press of the callout, instead of just its accessories, do not exist currently.